# Difference between three ways of referencing a variable

Tags: variables, assembly, x86-64, memory-address, att

I've noticed that all of the following three ways 'work' to access a variable in asm:

1. name it literally:

   ```
   .globl main
   number1:  .byte 7
   number2:  .byte 14
   main:
       mov number1,     %ebx
       mov number2,     %ecx
       mov $0,     %eax
   multiply_step:
       add %ebx,   %eax
       dec %ecx
       jnz multiply_step
       ret
   ```
2. name it with a `$` prepended:

   ```
   number1:  .byte 7         # use number1 = 7 or .equ to make this block work
   number2:  .byte 14
   main:
       mov $number1,     %ebx   # editor's note: this gets the address
       mov $number2,     %ecx   # not the value.
   ```
3. name it relative to `rip`:

   ```
   number1:  .byte 7
   number2:  .byte 14
   main:
       mov number1(%rip),     %ebx
       mov number2(%rip),     %ecx
   ```

All three give me the same product, `98`, when you multiply them like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63333752/delay-when-running-asm-program-with-named-variables).

What's the difference between these three ways to reference a variable, and is one of the ways preferred over the others?

Comment: None of these are calls, they're all just loads.  If you mean "naming" or "referencing", as in "what do I call you?", then say "three ways of referencing a variable".  Or e.g. "reference it relative to RIP".

Comment: Way #2 gives you their addresses.  Also, none of these will give you `98` in a register or anywhere else, and there's no `ret` on main so these aren't complete programs, and you aren't setting `main`'s return value (EAX) anyway.  The first and last give you `0x????0e07` in EBX, and `0x??????07` in ECX, where `??` comes from whatever bytes follow these 2 single bytes.  (You're  doing 4 byte loads).

Comment: 3. is preferred when you want the value: [Why is the address of static variables relative to the Instruction Pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40329260) / [Why are global variables in x86-64 accessed relative to the instruction pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56262889).  2. is preferred ([in a Linux non-PIE executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux) only) when you want the address, otherwise `lea foo(%rip), %rcx`.  Look at compiler output for functions that return the value or address of a global  var.

Comment: @PeterCordes I updated the code -- I left out the `globl main...ret` part to just focos on referencing the vars.